# Know what directives are allowed on apache server

Tags: apache

I'm trying to create a collabtive server.
For this, collabtive specify : Apache Web Server >= 2.0 compiled with mod_rewrite module and with the following directives allowed: DirectoryIndex, Deny, Allow, Options, Order, AddHandler, RewriteEngine, RewriteBase, RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

How can I know if these directives are allowed ? Do I need to change apache config to make it works ?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Apache functionality is organised into a series of modules.  Each module may be enabled (or disabled) in your Apache configuration files, to permit you to restrict and/or extend the capabilities you wish your server to have.  Some modules are enabled by default in a new Apache installation.

Modules can be enabled (in httpd.conf) with the `LoadModule` directive e.g. for mod_rewrite, the module is enabled with:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

There is an index of all of the available directives for the current Apache release available [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directives.html).  There is an index of all of the available modules for the current release available [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/).

For the specific directives you have asked about:

1. `RewriteEngine`, `RewriteBase`, `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` are provided by `mod_rewrite`.  If you have that module enabled, then you will have those directives available.
2. `Deny`, `Allow` and `Order` are access control directives that are deprecated for versions of Apache after v2.2.  For Apache v2.4+, you should use `Require` instead.  Examples of the new syntax are available [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).  You will usually need to enable `mod_authz_core` and `mod_authz_host` to make common `Require` options available.
3. `AddHandler` is provided by `mod_mime`.
4. `DirectoryIndex` is provided by `mod_dir`.
5. `Options` is part of Apache's core functionality and is always available.